# Lightning Filter Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, filters

We are building a component that allow user to search for list of records. Was wondering if there is a standard filter component that can be applied with the possibility to apply multiple fields and filter logic (similar to one we use on listviews).

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to create and define filters or would this be controlled by configuration / developer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Out of the box compnent that will meet your requirement - you will have to create your Own custom component + filter component or use an appexchange managed package that offers the functionality you are  looking for.